# Android Studio : Gradient background not showing in Button

Tags: android, button, gradient

Ok so my buttons are not showing gradient as they should be (the gradient is not showing, its just a normal color background), idk why this is happening, everything looks like how it should be to me, can someone please take a look :

**activity_main.xml**

```
...

   <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_room_service_24"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="40dp"
            android:text="BROWSE BY INGREDIENTS"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.084"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewPager"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.396" />
...
```

Here's a photo of the button as seen in the layout :
[button (gradient not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyeix.png)

**button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient
                android:startColor="#1746D3"
                android:endColor="#6D34CF"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="900dp"
                android:radius="90dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Here's a photo of the gradient background : [gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9FRy.png)

However, the `android:background="..."` does show the mini preview at the side : [button_preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFGWX.png)

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: Are you using a Material theme? Material Buttons do not support gradients or custom backgrounds, they only support a different color though `backgroundTint`

Comment: @TorkelVelure no am not using Material Button...
Its ok, @MarcoNardelotto 's answer worked out for me, i.e. changing `Button` to `AppCompatButton`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace in `Button` with `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` in `activity_main.xml`

It seems that using Button it is not possible to have the complete personalization of the widget.

`Button` widget handles its own background and you can only use tinting to change its color. This is an open issue and hasn't been fixed yet.